# PHP | Python map() equivalent

Tags: php, python

does PHP have an equivalent to Pythons Map()-Function?

If not, is it possible to build it on your own ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Yes. use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: How "equivalent" does it have to be? There's a bit of difference between `map` and `array_map`, but that's mostly due to how these languages work…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on vivek_23's comment.

**python**

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
squared = list(map(lambda x: x**2, items))
print(squared) // [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

**PHP (< 7.4)**

```
$items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$squared = array_map(function($x) { return $x ** 2; }, $items);
var_dump($squared); // [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

**PHP (7.4 +)**

[Arrow functions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions) have been introduced into PHP since version 7.4.

```
$items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$squared = array_map(fn($x) => $x ** 2, $items);
var_dump($squared); // [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```